# Creating a pivot table that selects all data in a sheet based on the active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new when it comes to VBA, so I'm sure this is very messy, but my end goal is to have a Global Macro that creates a pivot table from a selection of data then add it to a sheet previously made. The catch is that I'm trying to make the code work to where it will select all data no matter the amount of data inside the active sheet I'm working with.

With the section of code I keep getting

> Run-time Error '5': Invalid Procedure call or argument

I can assume this error is thrown because of the section on line 6. I have placed the line in question below and the full code at the bottom.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Cells(xlLastCell), _
```

In short, the Pivot table needs to select whatever data is within the current active sheet to use as a source.

The Help is greatly appreciated!

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(2)).Name = "Pivot Table"
Sheets("Loan Detail").Activate
Range("A1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Cells(xlLastCell), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Pivot Table!R3C3", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: Try `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

Comment: Sadly I'm still getting the same error. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

As per sktneer's comment, I've tested it using CurrentRegion and it worked for me:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(2)).Name = "Pivot Table"
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Sheets("Pivot Table").Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting a Run-Time Error '5' I also tried to create a separate Macro as well. It runs well until the actual pivot creation. 

Would it be easier to convert the data set I'm working with into a table, then create the pivot table from that?

Comment: ermm I'm not sure why that would be the case,... Did you update the Sheet name? and does the data start at Cell A1 or do you have a number of empty rows? Also you don't already have a Sheet named "Pivot Table" before you try creating a new one, right? I can't think of any other possible issues, as the code above works for me when testing...

Comment: Yes, the Macro that I use to format the sheet automatically names it to the Name I choose so there should be no errors there. The data does start at A1 and there should be no gaps that I have noticed (It's a lot of data). There are no other sheets named pivot table until the macro creates it. 

Is the amount of data the possible issue? I'm working with fields that fill up to columns BB and rows up too 12,000. I have my fields start at A1 and go to BB1, A2 and beyond is the actual data.

Comment: @Stapes, I'm stumped, everything you mentioned seems like the correct way to go about it, the amount of data shouldn't be an issue as it isn't any more than Excel can handle, so I'm out of suggestions... Could you maybe add a link to your spreadsheet in the comments so I could have a look at it?

Comment: @Stapes did you also replace the `Sheet1` in my answer to `Loan Detail` as it was in your question? The only thing I can think of is that you are using the ActiveSheet, instead of fully qualifying it to Sheets("Loan Detail")...?

Comment: Sadly I cannot give access to the spreadsheet as it contains sensitive data. Yes I did change it to "Loan Detail" so I'm honestly stumped as well. Thank you for the help though! I will try and figure it out by playing with what you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general code for creating Pivot Table. You may use this code for reference.

Also, you may download the workbook from the following link...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14bAhfPhbl3PNUkVc5kX4gUdtKLCDpiF0

**Code to create Pivot Table:**

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim rngSource As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
On Error Resume Next
Set wsPivot = Sheets("Pivot")
wsPivot.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If wsPivot Is Nothing Then
    Set wsPivot = Sheets.Add(before:=wsData)
    wsPivot.Name = "Pivot"
End If

Set rngSource = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Creating Pivot Cache
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource)

'Creating Pivot Table
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(wsPivot.Range("A3"), "SalesPivot")

'Adding Row and Column Fields
pt.AddFields RowFields:="Name", ColumnFields:="Day"

'Adding Data Field
pt.AddDataField field:=pt.PivotFields("Sales"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

'Adding Data Field Formatting
pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

'Disable the Grand Total for Rows
pt.RowGrand = False

'Disable the Grand Total for Columns
pt.ColumnGrand = False

'Setting layout to Tabular View
pt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

'Sorting the Row Field
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Name")

'Sorting Descending
pf.AutoSort xlDescending, pf

'Sorting Ascending
pf.AutoSort xlAscending, pf

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will play around with it and see if I can get my code to work.